# php form action based on user logged in or not

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi I am learning PHP by building a web application. Ive run into a bit of a problem / confusion which I cant seem to figure out.

Here is my page

[image]

In the image above the user made the following selections as can be seen on the image.

**USER LOGGED ON**

If the user is logged on proceed to upload.php to upload his selections

**USER NOT LOGGED ON**

If the user is NOT logged on redirect to index.php (for testing purpose)

To accomplish the above I did the following (which is not very pretty)

```
<form name="selections" id="makeSelection" method="post"  action="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($userLogged)){ //user is logged on upload selections
        echo'upload.php'; 
    }
    else if(!isset($userLogged)){ //user is NOT logged on redirect
    echo'index.php';    
    }
} ?>">
```

Regardless if the user is logged or not the script just refreshes the current page. Any advice on what I can do to solve my problem will be much appreciated

Comment: check the action of the form, what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking that the form was already submit, meaning that the first time the action will be blank, and defaulting to `self` (current script), remove the first if: `<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

```
<form name="selections" id="makeSelection" method="post"  action="<?php 
    if(isset($userLogged)){ //user is logged on upload selections
        echo'upload.php'; 
    }
    else if(!isset($userLogged)){ //user is NOT logged on redirect
    echo'index.php';    
    }
} ?>">
```

Or perform a better check:

```
<?php
    $action = (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($userLogged)) ? 'upload.php' : 'index.php';
?>
<form name="selections" id="makeSelection" method="post"  action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
```

This way, you check that the form was submitted and the user is logged in to send the form to `upload.php`, otherwise, send it to `index.php`.

Comment: That is exactly what happened the form when page is loaded just said " " thanks I will change it and see what happens

Comment: IM getting a syntax error on your edit with `$action` sorry but I cant spot the mistake is it perhaps the `?` after `isset($userLogged))`

Comment: my mistake, typo there, missing parenthesis. just corrected it.